# UWP File Management

Tags: c#, file, uwp, save, load

Why does saving a file fail so often on UWP?

I open and read the contents of a specified file when the application is initially launched (with the help of a `BackgroundWorker`). Then when the application is suspending I try to save new content to the same file, however this results almost always in the following exception:

> Unable to remove the file to be replaced. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070497)

My loading method:

```
private async static void SymbolLoader_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        IStorageItem file = null;

        if (!UseDefault)
        {
            var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(SavePath);
            file = await folder.TryGetItemAsync(FileName);
        }

        if (file == null)
        {
            file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\Default.txt");
        }

        var text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync((IStorageFile)file);

        Data = DoSomething(text);
}
```

My `OnSuspending` method:

```
private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
        var tries = 0;
        var maxTries = 10;
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();

        while (tries < maxTries)
        {
            var completed = await Saver.Save();

            if (completed)
                break;
            else
            {
                tries++;
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
            }
        }

        deferral.Complete();
}
```

`Save` method:

```
public static async Task<bool> Save()
{
        //some formatting etc.

        var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(SavePath);
        var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(FileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        try
        {
            await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(file, lines);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

It is critical that the data is saved, which is why I "solved" the problem by trying to save the file multiple times with some delay. However my solution, presented in the `OnSuspending` method, does not seem like the correct way to do this.

What is the correct approach? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using `CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists` instead of `ReplaceExisting` when calling `folder.CreateFileAsync`?

Comment: Your solution seems to work significantly better, however the same exception is still occasionally thrown.

Comment: Well, it depends on what're you doing with that file. If your `BackgroundWorker` is working with the file while you're trying to do something else with it, it may throw an exception.

Comment: The file should not be in use when it is about to be saved. The problem might solve itself when building a release build, I have to check this.